# How to set a time based trigger for a spreadsheet created from the script in another 'parent' spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a spreadsheet containing a script.
In this script I created another spreadsheet, called TP.
I want to set Triggers in this TP spreadsheet.
That is easy for the onopen trigger.

```
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("agendaCheck")
    .forSpreadsheet(TP)
   .onOpen()
   .create();
```

But for the time based trigger I can't do this.

```
     ScriptApp.newTrigger("agendaCheck")
     .forSpreadsheet(TP)
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(3)
    .everyDays(1) 
    .create();
```

This runs an error: can't find function timeBased in object SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder...

Comment: I m thinking about a workaround.  I could create the TP spreadsheet by copying a template, which has a script.  In this local script I put a function (makeTimeBaseTrigger).  Then I set an onopen trigger form the parent spreadsheet running the makeTimeBaseTrigger function.  Only problem is that I propably have to autorize first time it runs...  So no good ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder` class only gives access to simple triggers (`onOpen()`, `onEdit()`, etc). You need to use:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
   .timeBased()
   .atHour(3)
   .everyDays(1)
   .create();
```

and bind `myFunction` to a function which accesses the TP spreadsheet.